# Angular <component> is not a known element of a module even if I declare exports

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

So, I have created a module, inside that module I have a Navbar component declared like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

In the module I have this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UsuariosComponent } from './usuarios/usuarios.component';
import { ProductosComponent } from './productos/productos.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [NavComponent, UsuariosComponent, ProductosComponent, ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    NavComponent,
    UsuariosComponent,
    ProductosComponent
  ],
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

and in the module component html I have the selector like this:

```
<app-nav></app-nav>

<h1>Dashboard</h1>
```

then in my app-module.ts I have the module imported, here's the file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LandingHeadComponent } from './components/landing-head/landing-head.component';
import { ProyectosSliderComponent } from './components/proyectos-slider/proyectos-slider.component';
import { ProductosLandingComponent } from './components/productos-landing/productos-landing.component';
import { TestimoniosComponent } from './components/testimonios/testimonios.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { InicioComponent } from './inicio/inicio.component';
import { ProyectosComponent } from './proyectos/proyectos.component';
import { ContactoComponent } from './contacto/contacto.component';
import { CatalogoComponent } from './catalogo/catalogo.component';
import { InicioSesionComponent } from './components/inicio-sesion/inicio-sesion.component';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AdminHomeComponent } from './components/admin-home/admin-home.component';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LandingHeadComponent,
    ProyectosSliderComponent,
    ProductosLandingComponent,
    TestimoniosComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    InicioComponent,
    ProyectosComponent,
    ContactoComponent,
    CatalogoComponent,
    InicioSesionComponent,
    AdminHomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    DashboardModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And it keeps throwing this error

```
'app-nav' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-nav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-nav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2 <app-nav></app-nav>
```

Any suggestions? I've been battling this for hours :(

Edit: this is my module, perhaps I'm having an error in the way I handle this?

[Module Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrYPV.png)

I want to archive something like this:

[Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BakZ9.png)

Comment: Your code looks good, Try restarting your CLI  - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44430230/11719787)

Comment: Already done that, didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!!**

It turns out I was not declaring my component to the module!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are importing **NavComponent** into two modules, you should just import it into **DashboardModule** and then import **DashboardModule** into **AppModule**.

I hope it helps.