# notifier-container is not a known element unable to use angular-notifier

Tags: angular

I've been trying to use the angular notifier package for a project,
I installed it correctly and made the right customs, but when i try to lauch it it says that notifier-container is not a known element. Nowhere in the doc it is explained that i should create any component.
Has someon ever used it ?
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 'component' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429996/angular-2-component-is-not-a-known-element)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for anyone having the same issue you need to put it into the app-component and not into the file where you want it to appear !